# How to encode label ("class_encode_column") on a streaming dataset ("IterableDataset")

Tags: huggingface-datasets

How does one load a CSV dataset as an IterableDataset with the `streaming=True` flag and then cast a given column as ClassLabel? This is fairly straightforward with a dataset where `streaming=False`:

```
data_files = { "train": train_data_file, "test": test_data_file, 'validation': valid_data_file }
dataset = load_dataset(
    'csv',
    data_files=data_files,
    streaming=True,
)
dataset.with_format("torch")
dataset = dataset.class_encode_column("label")
```

However this exact code with `streaming=False` will throw the error `AttributeError: 'IterableDatasetDict' object has no attribute 'class_encode_column'`.

It errors out calling the collate_fn when attempting to iterate `DataLoader` , specifically at `self.tokenizer.pad(...)`. This makes sense because then the `features` argument in `__call__` of the data collator, `label` is the raw text label rather than the encoded label. I'm not sure how to class encode this for a streaming dataset.

My initial guess is to just encode this column in data processing. However, is there anyway to encode this label feature here instead, in a similar fashion as is done with datasets that are loaded into memory?